# Attempting to download json file from DnDBeyond gives 403 error

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am making a D&D bot which downloads character sheets from DnDBeyond. Unfortunately, attempting to download the json file for a publicly-available character keeps returning 403 error.

I'm trying to download this character sheet: 
https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/22738330/json

which is publicly available and should return a json file.

I used the following code:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/22738330/json"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.json())
```

Which keeps returning 403 error despite the fact that I am able to load the character on my browser by simply clicking on it. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How many times have you run this script?  The website might be denying you for excessive usage.

Comment: Also, the urls in the question body and the code example do not match.  The code url does not have `/json` at the end.

Comment: Add `headers` in your script. this URL return `HTML` data, So use response.content .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a valid User-Agent and other headers to make it seem like you're accessing via a browser.

Something like this:

```
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3835.0 Safari/537.36',
       'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Host':'www.dndbeyond.com',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
       'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
       'Connection': 'close'
    }


response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: That only downloads the HTML, not the JSON. But it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

This site protected by https://www.perimeterx.com/whywasiblocked/

It detect that you are not real user and deny access for you.
check output of `response.text` in you script.

Comment: How do you find the site is protected by PerimeterX?

Comment: check output of response.text in you script:


... Powered by <a href="https://www.perimeterx.com/whywasiblocked">PerimeterX</a> ...

Answer (score 0):

To access the json, you need to remove the plural on path component "characters".

As for the data format, I'm nearly done fleshing out the entire structure.

Objective-C source include all class definitions.

https://github.com/mouser/BeyondDnD